# Missunderstanding append() or a treatement in Js/JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need a bit of comprehension on this one pls :

Its a function to sort by price product. Only problem is that I dont get why I dont have to empty my table before appending the products

**[Here is a playground](https://jsfiddle.net/Baldrani/gb9yvrc5/)**

This is the code

```
$length = $('[data-th="Prix : "]').length;
$dispo = $('.productsDispo');
$temp = 0;
for(var i = 0; i < $length; i++)
{   
    for(var j = i; j < $length; j++)
    {
        $prixI = $($dispo[i]).find($('[data-th="Prix : "]')).text().slice(0, $($dispo[i]).find($('[data-th="Prix : "]')).text().length-2);
        $prixJ = $($dispo[j]).find($('[data-th="Prix : "]')).text().slice(0, $($dispo[j]).find($('[data-th="Prix : "]')).text().length-2);

        if(parseInt($prixI) < parseInt($prixJ))
        {
          $temp = $dispo[i];
          $dispo[i] = $dispo[j];
          $dispo[j] = $temp;
        }
    }
}
for(var i = 0; i < $length; i++)
{  
    $('.rwd-table tbody').append($dispo[i])
}
```

Comment: Why would you need to empty the table to add more things to it?

Comment: @senschen I do not add, I Sort them

Answer (score 3):

That's because of how `append` works in jQuery. From [docs](http://api.jquery.com/append/):

> If an element selected this way is inserted into a single location elsewhere in the DOM, it will be moved into the target (not cloned):

Since you do the sorting and appending manipulating the very DOM objects you selected, they are already in the table, and you basically move them inside the table with `append`.

Comment: Waow so append is an hell of a function ! Thanks for pointing it to me, I was only using it before for inserting created elements.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery's `append` does not make a clone of an element that you pass to it. It 'cuts' the element from its old location and 'pastes' it into a new one.

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/3ro4sov5/1)'s a simpler example that shows this behavior, if anyone needs it illustrated.